# TFS 2018 - Building pre-release packages

Tags: tfs

I'm using "TFS 2018 Update 2" and trying to build a package marked as a pre-release according to the [microsoft semantic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages)

I tried using the **.nuspec file** inserting the  (ex: 1.0.0-beta and changing the **Build number format** as: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)$(Suffix)
setting the $(Suffix) variable at queue time.

Every attempt failed: the package never contains the suffix, than is never marked as pre-release.
I see that the nuget pack command never contains the suffix (missing "-beta" after "2018.6.12.9"). In my test build **$Suffix is set to "-beta"**:

> nuget.exe pack
>   C:\agent_work\4\s\DotNetClassicLibrary\DotNetClassicLibrary.csproj
>   -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory C:\agent_work\4\a -Properties Configuration=debug -version 2018.6.12.9 -Verbosity Detailed

The Build task on TFS is:

> "DotNetClassicLibrary / Build DotNetClassicLibrary_2018.6.12.9-beta /
>   Job / NuGet pack"

So I'm sure that the variable is assigned because of the presence of the suffix **"-beta"** in the path.

Here there is the configuration of the nuget pack task

[image: Nuget Pack]

This is the Build number format

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario on my side. In my opinion, `Nuget pack` task with build number doesn't support character or numbers. You may check [this task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NuGetCommandV2/nugetpack.ts) and try to modify it.

```
case "byBuildNumber":
                tl.debug("Getting version number from build number")

                if(tl.getVariable("SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE") === "release")
                {
                    tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, tl.loc("Error_AutomaticallyVersionReleases"));
                    return;
                }

                let buildNumber: string =  tl.getVariable("BUILD_BUILDNUMBER");
                tl.debug(`Build number: ${buildNumber}`);

                let versionRegex = /\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?/;
                let versionMatches = buildNumber.match(versionRegex);
                if (!versionMatches)
                {
                    tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, tl.loc("Error_NoVersionFoundInBuildNumber"));
                    return;
                }

                if (versionMatches.length > 1)
                {
                    tl.warning(tl.loc("Warning_MoreThanOneVersionInBuildNumber"))
                }

                version = versionMatches[0];
                break;
```

> As an alternative, you could choose `Nuget custom`, and specify the
>   pack command there with parameter `-version $(Build.BuildNumber)`,
>   I've tried on my side, this works.

Comment: Hi Cece, I used the "Nuget custom" as you suggested and it works! Just a question. For the "Command and arguments" I inserted: "pack $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\DotNetClassicLibrary\DotNetClassicLibrary.csproj  -OutputDirectory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Properties Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) -version $(Build.BuildNumber) -Verbosity Detailed" and I modified the "Build number format" removing $(BuildDefinitionName) to exclude the name in the build number. Did you find a better solution for this arguments?

Comment: No, you can either remove `$(BuildDefinitionName)` from build number. Or you can use script to filter the build number to match `versionRegex` as `nuget pack` task and then use parameter `-version $(BuildNumberFilter) -Suffix Beta` to pack the package.